# Is it a good idea to use GWT with HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am new to GWT. I started using it three days ago with HTML5 Canvas for drawing some basic shapes with basic animation (nothing fancy, just straight lines moving up and down).
Before moving to GWT, I wrote some javascript code to do the same thing.

And I noticed that javascript is a lot faster in rendering the shapes than GWT. Considering that GWT is also javascript, is there something that I do not know that is slowing GWT down? I also want to know if it is a good idea to use GWT for canvas at all, or is it a better idea to stick to javascript for drawing on cavas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you run your GWT application? In development mode? In development mode the code runs much slower than in production. If you compile your application and deploy it to an application server it should be as fast as native javascript (because then it is actually native javascript! :))

Comment: Yes, I am running in development mode.

Comment: Any lost soul who comes here may find this useful:

compile the project and just delete the "gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997" part at the end of the address in the browser in the development mode.
The code runs like a white hot knife through butter.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would suggest taking a strong look at dart. It compiles down to faster javascript than GWT and is looking to have greater support by google in general.

GWT produces javascript that is generally around 1.5->2.0 slower than native javascript. For a business app, that usually isn't a big deal.  GWT makes a lot of sense when you are looking for backwards compatibility and strong support for java and java like features.

Where you are using HTML5, the compatibility benefit of GWT becomes moot.  At that point, you are targeting the browsers which dart supports.

(The "why" gwt is slower has to do with java.  GWT has to do a lot of work to ensure that java constraints and behavior is maintained.  Dart was designed with an eye towards javascript compilation)

Comment: Do you have some kind of source for this numbers?

Comment: For GWT, personal experience (I'm looking for some benchmarks to confirm/disprove).  For dart, yup http://www.dartlang.org/performance/

Comment: The "why" gwt is slower:  I haven't heard this before. On the contrary the gwt javascript generated is supposed to be super optimized

Comment: I guess the Dart team has put more effort into optimizing the output of the Dart2js compiler for the Javascript VMs and might be faster than GWT steering committee. However this is also on the roadmap of the new GWT. 
I highly doubt that GWT generates javascript code that's 2 times slower than handwritten code at least for normal web app like code.
 
Just for completeness here is a benchmark: http://j15r.com/blog/2011/12/15/Box2D_as_a_Measure_of_Runtime_Performance

But that's for a game engine which is a special case

Comment: I would gladly straight away use javascript all by itself or use Dart if it turns out to be as good as you say it is, but my project is part of a bigger whole which is developed in GWT, so I have to stick to GWT.

Answer (score 0):

the Only advantage i can seen in using GWTCanvas is browser compatibility. Its mainly focused on the browser support. It doesn't have all the features implemented in HTML5 Canvas element. If you are looking for all the canvas features then better to move along with javascript.